# How to write loop to optimize the given number

Tags: r

I have some amount (value) say x= 7180.7 ,need to divide this amount to five variables say A=1225.00,B=355.25,C=6775.00 ,D=253.85,E=235.00 such that the  remainder value of x should be as low as possible.

Ex: From x=7180.7 I can have 3*A (3*1225=3675), 3*B (3*355.25 ), 4*D (4*253.85) , 4*E (4*235.00) .

3*A + 3*B + 0*C + 4*D + 4*E= 6696.15   Difference=7180.7-6696.15=484.55

like this I can get different combination of A,B,C,D ,but I want the best possible of A,B,C,D which minimises the difference .

I have tried the below code :

```
RemAmt=c(As,Bs,Cs,Ds,Es)
sumrem=AmtArem+AmtBrem+AmtCrem+AmtDrem+AmtErem
```

Comment: This is actually an interesting problem (if I understand), but it is not well explained. Using multiples of a set of five numbers what is the combination that gets closest to some target value without exceeding it. The question then is what is an efficient approach to systematically arrive at the result.

Comment: This is an integer programming/optimizing problem. I think for the given values you can try all combinations with coefficients for A lower than 6, cB lower than 20, ...

Comment: Can you proof read your question _very_ carefully and make edits as necessary?  In your example, why is there 2A, 3B, **no C**, 4D, and then **4**E?  And also, when in the parenthesis of your example do you say things like **2A (3*...)**?  Also, why is there a **D*E**?

Comment: Also please include any attempt from your side at finding a computational solution. Otherwise this sounds too much like a “gimme teh codez” question. I agree with @AaronHayman in that this may be an interesting code challenge. Even more so you should try for yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution of the problem:

```
x <- 7180.7
Parts <- c(A=1225.00, B=355.25, C=6775.00, D=253.85, E=235.00)
maxCoef <- x %/% Parts
prod(maxCoef+1) ### number of combinations
Comb <- expand.grid(A=0:maxCoef["A"], B=0:maxCoef["B"], C=0:maxCoef["C"], 
            D=0:maxCoef["D"], E=0:maxCoef["E"])
Comb$residuum <- x - as.matrix(Comb) %*% Parts 
Comb$residuum <- ifelse(Comb$residuum<0, 9999, Comb$residuum)
i <- which.min(Comb$residuum)
Comb[i, ]
# > Comb[i, ]
#        A B C  D  E residuum
# 112903 0 1 0 13 15      0.4
```

The call to `expand.grid()` can be shorten to

```
expand.grid(lapply(maxCoef, ':', 0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jog,It works now.

Comment: @PraveenChougale **Please close this question by setting the green check mark next to the answer.** This also applies to *all* of your other questions for which you have gotten an answer.